# Troubles with Boolean Algebra

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic

maybe there is a simple solution for my Problem, but I cannot find it! Following Problem (in Java program):

Log.d(TAG, "----------------------> " + ((x < LEFT_X) || (x > RIGHT_X)));

Assuming, that LEFT_X = 100 and RIGHT_X = 1000

if the value of x = 50, then the output is TRUE -> that is what I ecpected

if the value of x = 1050, then the output = TRUE -> that is what I expected

if the value of x = 500, the output = TRUE too -> but here I would expect FALSE (because FALSE OR FALSE = FALSE)!

What do I made wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't somewhere else? The reasoning itself seems correct to me.

Comment: Try to log the exact values in your expression apart from each other, e.g. Log.d("{} {} {}", x, LEFT_X, RIGHT_X);

Answer (score 0):

found my mistake! I should use the right variables (leftX instead the constant LEFT_X)